# facebook login Javascript SDK - button only works some of the time?

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication

I have the following simple code for facebook website login below. I tested the site in a mozilla browser and everything worked fine, opening up a prompt for me to login to facebook, but when I tried again on a windows OS with chrome, my button does not do anything. This is especially frustrating because it looks like the button works - but only sometimes, and I have no idea why. I am hosting my site through google app engine.

I've been trying to figure this out for ages, any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
  // Additional JS functions here
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'xxx', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//http://www.XXX.com/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });
  };

function doLogin(){
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
         login();
      } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
         login();
      } else {
         login();
      }
     });
}

function login() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            testAPI();
        } else {
            // cancelled
        }
    }, {scope: 'email,user_education_history,user_work_history'}); //permissions
}

function testAPI() {
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        alert('Good to see you, ' + response.email + '.');
    });
}

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
```

And my html button:

```
  <button style="position:absolute; margin-top: 4px;margin-left:600px;" onclick="doLogin();">Sign Up With Facebook</button>
```

EDIT:

When I check the console in my chrome browser where the button doesnt work, I receive the following message:

Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

Again, the button works perfectly fine when I am running it in my mozilla browser in my linux OS but not on my other computer. I am still not sure what is causing this difference?? Thanks again all for your help.

Comment: That will most likely be the browser’s popup blocker. Modern browsers in default settings block popups that are not opened upon _direct_ user interaction. And since `FB.getLoginStatus` works asynchronously, your call to `login` and therein `FB.login` has no more “direct” connection between the user’s button click and the method call. Either call `FB.getLoginStatus` after initializing the SDK and save the result, or call `FB.login` directly upon button click (the popup will close by itself almost immediately if the user is already logged in).

Comment: Based on the edit, I'd say you have a race condition between multiple calls to FB.init with different app id's.

Comment: Thanks guys! I just tried a direct call to FB.login inside a wrapper function and looks like it is working now. Thanks!